# Erlang ETS insert/2 error

Tags: concurrency, erlang, erlang-shell, ets

I am trying to create a simple Erlang process with the access to ETS module.

My source code includes:

1. Process creation:

   ```
   start_message_channel() ->
       Table = ets:new(messages, [ordered_set, named_table]),
       Channel = spawn(?MODULE, channel, []),
       {Channel, {table, Table}}.
   ```
2. Process logic:

   ```
   channel() ->
       receive
           {Sender, {send_message, {Message, Table}}} ->
               ets:insert(Table, {message, Message}),
               Sender ! {self(), {status, success}};
           {Sender, {receive_message, Table}} ->
               {message, Message} = ets:first(Table),
               Sender ! {self(), {status, {success, Message}}};
           _ ->
               throw(incorrect_protocol_exception)
   end.
   ```
3. Communication with process

   ```
   send_message_to_message_channel({Channel, {table, Table}}, Message) ->
       Channel ! {self(), {send_message, {Message, Table}}},
       receive
           {Channel, {status, success}} ->
               io:format("Message sent!~n");
           {Channel, {status, failure}} ->
               io:format("Message failed to send!~n");
           _ ->
               throw(incorrect_protocol_exception)
   end.

   receive_message_from_message_channel({Channel, {table, Table}}) ->
       Channel ! {self(), {receive_message, Table}},
       receive
           {Channel, {status, {success, Message}}} ->
               io:format(Message);
           {Channel, {status, failure}} ->
               io:format("Message failed to receive!~n");
           _ ->
               throw(incorrect_protocol_exception)
   end.
   ```

While executing function calls in Erlang terminal, I am getting error:

```
    1> cd("C:/Users/dauma").                    
    C:/Users/dauma
    ok
    2> c(message_channel).
    {ok,message_channel}
    3> Object = message_channel:start_message_channel().
    {<0.59.0>,{table,messages}}
    4> message_channel:send_message_to_message_channel(Object, "Hello World!").

    =ERROR REPORT==== 19-May-2016::11:09:27 ===
    Error in process <0.59.0> with exit value:
    {badarg,[{ets,insert,[messages,"Hello World!"],[]},
        {message_channel,channel,0,
            [{file,"message_channel.erl"},{line,35}]}]}
```

Could anyone tell me, where might be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ETS tables are owned by an Erlang process, and have access controls. By default the table is `protected` and can only be written to by the process that owns it, though it can be read from other processes.

If you want to read and write from a different process, use `public`.

```
Table = ets:new(messages, [ordered_set, named_table, public])
```

You can also use `private`, which means that only the owning process can read and write.

Per [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#protected):

> - `public` Any process may read or write to the table.
> - `protected` The owner process can read and write to the table. Other processes can only read the table. This is the default setting for the access rights.
> - `private` Only the owner process can read or write to the table.

In your example, you create the table in one process (the one calling `start_message_channel`), and then you attempt to call `ets:insert` from a different process: `spawn(?MODULE, channel, [])` creates a new process, with `channel` as its entry point.

Because your table is not marked as `public`, the call to `ets:insert` from the other process fails with `badarg`.

Per [the documentation, again](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#id183025):

> In general, the functions below will exit with reason `badarg` if any argument is of the wrong format, if the table identifier is invalid or if the operation is denied due to table access rights (`protected` or `private`).

---

Side note: if you use `named_table`, the value returned from `ets:new` *is* the table name, so you can do this:

```
-define(TABLE, messages).

% later...
?TABLE = ets:new(?TABLE, [named_table, ordered_set, protected])
```

...and you don't need to store the returned value in state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! After the small changes you suggested, everything works like a charm! For the better understanding, could you tell, in my example, isn't the same process which created table updates it?

Comment: You create the table in #1, and then spawn a process to run channel/0. That's the process doing the insert, hence being private doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, but default is `protected`.

Comment: @rvirding, true (I can never remember, so I tend to be explicit); updated my answer.